# Formula for transpose matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

I ran by an exercise in my textbook that got me writing sheets of paper of matrix multiplications, and I got a lot of ($ij$ entry)$^2$, but that was not enough for me to construct a convincing argument for the exercise..

Anyone that can come up with a clearer solution, would be really appreciated!

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Hint. If you think of the rows of $A$ as vectors then the $ij$ entry in $AA^T$ is ...? (think dot product).

Comment: @EthanBolker I think I'm starting to understand the idea! 
I'll write it down and post it here to see if I got it correctly, 3 min

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put it down in words(i mean, matrices) the hint that ethan gave me, but I'm not sure I wrote it all down correctly, is it right?

Btw, thanks for the hint mate

Each A$ij$ is a dot product of the same vector, so if , by the exercise, we assume it is $0$, then all of the other entries are $0$, because it is a combination involving [V$ij$]

[image]

Comment: I think you want $v_{ij} = [v_i]\cdot[v_j] = 0$. What does this tell you about each row dotted with itself?